# Android Button onClick Enter text

Tags: android, xml, url, button

I've seen it a BILLION times but can't find the answer. How do I enter a predefined text in a edittext box on click? I want the button to read a statement and when the user clicks the button the url attached to the text is displayed.

Comment: All the code here worked! Thank You everybody that took time to assist me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hope this helps you

```
button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    final String _url = "http://yoururl";
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            editText.setText(_url);
        }
    });
```

Comment: here is my xml
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" />

I want to send data onClick to the editText field

Answer (score 4):

not sure what you want...

```
final EditText edit = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
Button btn = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);

btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        edit.setText("your text");
    }

});
```

Comment: Seconded, I was typing basically exactly this.

Answer (score 1):

EditText.setText("Your text here");

That is all you need to do.  (Well, wrap it in your click listener and get the id, but I assume you know that).